# Is there a near-repdigit prime of every size?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Define a near-repdigit prime as a prime number where all but one of the digits are the same. For example $199, 94999$  and $76777$ are near-repdigit primes.

Is there a near-repdigit prime with $n$ digits for all $n>1$?

I realise that a lot of these types of questions are open. Is this in fact an open question?

---

A stronger conjecture is the following. Does there in fact exist a near-repdigit prime with $n$ digits whose first digit is $1$ for all $n>1$?

I have checked for near-repdigit primes starting with the digit 1 and there is at least one for all $n \leq 3495$.

---

Following a suggestion of @ErickWong I counted how many counter-examples there are for both the stronger conjecture and the original conjecture  in base 2,3, 4 and 5 for $2 \leq n \leq 2000$.

- base 2: Stronger 269, original 269
- base 3: Stronger 58, original 58
- base 4: Stronger 3, original 3
- base 5: There are 0 counter-examples for both the stronger and the original conjecture.

For every case where there is no near-repdigit prime with the first digit being 1, there is no near-repdigit prime with that number of digits and in that base at all.

Comment: @Hersh 199 is an all-but-one prime isn't it?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A258915 and https://oeis.org/A164937 - The term is near-repdigit prime.

Comment: @vvg thank you very much. Maybe the answer is known?

Comment: Well, for $n>2$, there are $81n$ candidates, each heuristically a prime with probability $\frac1{\ln10^n}$, so we *expect* about $35$ all-but-one primes per $n$. But such heuristics are far from rigorous

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I guess even for that heuristic we need to understand something about the variance to know if it can ever be 0.

Comment: @graffe These things are usually well-modeled by Poisson distributions (the primality of different numbers is more or less independent), so Hagen von Eitzen's comment suggests a roughly $1/e^{35}$ chance of no primes.  Very small but nonzero.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is open and there are infinite many such primes. Even the number of rep-unit primes is probably infinite. Factordb contains some huge near-rep-digit primes , indicating that there should be infinite many. The stronger conjecture, that there is such a prime with every given number of digits should also be true.

Comment: Would you be content with a list of such primes with , say , $2,3,\cdots,100$ digits ?

Comment: I suspect this is one of those conjectures that is probably true but is unproven and will remain unproven for a very long time indeed. The $1/e^{35}$ chance given above for no primes of a given length suggests, by the law of large numbers, that the conjecture might be false. You'll need to check out a thousand to a million times that number of digits to get a likely miss, but when you're already talking about numbers with a quadrillion digits, what's five or six quadrillion more? Still less than Skewes' number!

Comment: @EricSnyder You are probably right. But should I delete the question in that light?

Comment: No, of course not. It obviously generated some interest and discussion. But some questions we just... can't answer yet. Possibly never will be able to.

Comment: If the probability $P(n)$ that there is no prime with $n$ digits is bounded (no matter what $n$ is) , then we can in fact expect that the conjecture should be false (although this is of course no proof that it is false). But to get an impression how difficult it will be to find a counterexample, consider the linked question where the problem is significantly restricted and yet we can still find a prime upto $n=2\ 000$.

Comment: But this does not mean that the question should be deleted ! It is nice that there occur interesting questions about prime numbers at all (even if they are out of reach, which is anyway usually the case).

Comment: Near-repunit primes, https://oeis.org/A105992 may interest you.

Comment: The stronger conjecture seems to limit you to testing $9n$ numbers for each $n$.  This should be much easier to falsify, with the smallest expected counterexample having only $100$ to $1000$ digits.

Comment: @mjqxxxx  Any suggestions for how you might go about falsifying it? An exhaustive search at that scale isn't possible.

Comment: @graffe Not true ! Numbers with $100$ to $1\ 000$ digits can easily and fast be checked for primality (even if one insists in a primality proof). If we find ONE such prime, we can immediately stop for the particular number of digits. Even if we must check all the numbers , this won't take very long. Of course this slows seriously down if we arrive at , say , $10\ 000$ digits. But maybe you mean that the smallest counterexample might be too large. This can of course be the case.

Comment: Since the $e^{35}$ factor is dependent on the base, it should be fruitful to look for counterexamples in smaller bases and see how close we can get to base $10$.  Binary should be common enough that we can even consider the density of counterexamples.

Comment: Based on the $541$-candidates (numbers that are not divisible by a prime $p\le 541$) , the expected number of primes in my linked question (where we start with ones and change any digit , not the first and not the last) is at least $6.5$ (in most cases $8-12$) , if the number of digits is in the range $[500,7\ 000]$. For $3-500$ digits , there are (proven) primes. Here we have much more choices.

Answer (score 6):

The $n$-digit numbers of this form can be parametrized as $A\cdot\frac{10^n-1}{9} + (B-A)\cdot10^k$, where $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$, $A \in \{1,2,\ldots, 9\}$, and $B\neq A\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$.  So, as pointed out in comments, there are exactly $81n$ numbers of this form for a given $n$.  If there's nothing "special" about these numbers (nothing making them more or less likely to be prime except their size), then each is prime with probability about $1/(n\log 10)$, and the probability that none are prime, for large $n$, behaves like
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n\log 10}\right)^{81n}\approx e^{-81/\log 10}\approx e^{-35.2} \approx 5.3\times10^{-16}.
$$
In other words, it's very likely for any particular $n$ that there's a near-repdigit prime of that length.  But (still assuming there's nothing special about the numbers), there should be infinitely many $n$ for which there are no near-repdigit primes of length $n$, and we can expect the smallest such $n$ to be of order $10^{15}$ or so.

Based on the OEIS sequence [A258915](https://oeis.org/A258915), the actual number of near-repdigit primes is somewhat higher than expected for smallish $n$: we expect $35.2$ on average by the above analysis, but the actual mean is more like $44$.  This can most likely be explained by examining divisibility of these numbers by small primes.  For instance, while half of all numbers are divisible by $2$, only about $4/9$ of the numbers we're testing are (mainly those where $A$ is even), leading to a higher fraction of primes.  Similarly, one-fifth of all numbers are divisible by $5$, but only about $1/9$ of the numbers we're testing are (mainly those with $A=5$).  Taking this extra data into account, we might adjust our expectation quantitatively... the smallest counterexample may be more like $10^{19}$... but the qualitative conclusion is unchanged.

---

The stronger conjecture, that for each $n$ there is a near-repdigit prime of length $n$ whose first digit is a $1$, should be much easier to falsify.  The $n$-digit numbers of this form are those where either (a) $A=1$ and $k<n-1$ (all $1$s except a single digit), or (b) $B=1$ and $k=n-1$ (only the first digit is a $1$).  There are $9n$ of these numbers, making the naive probability that none are prime
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n\log 10}\right)^{9n} \approx e^{-9/\log 10}\approx e^{-3.91} \approx 0.02.
$$
So you shouldn't have to check that many values of $n$ to find a counterexample.  The same reasoning applies for the other possible first digits; there should be abundant counterexamples for all of them.  As with the main problem, they are expected to be somewhat less abundant than this analysis suggests, but should still be in reach of a feasible computer search.

---

*Update*:
I've searched through $n=500$ for counterexamples to the stronger conjecture, both for numbers starting with $1$ (OP's conjecture) and for numbers starting with $3$, $7$, or $9$ (the other initial digits are easy to find counterexamples for, for obvious reasons) and haven't found any yet.  Empirically the number of near-repdigit primes (probable primes, in practice) for each of these starting digits averages $11$ or so, as compared to the expected $3.91$.  This makes the expected smallest counterexample more like $n=10^4$ or $10^5$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). You mentioned it , to get a better heuristic where the smallest counterexample might lie , we need a more careful analysis concerning the small prime numbers. I do not know whether you proved the primality , or you relied on BPSW (the latter beings much more speed and the probability of a failure is virtually zero).

Comment: Even a counterexample for my much stronger conjecture in the linked question could be out of reach.

Comment: No, I just used a simple Fermat test for probable primality.  So, no risk of a false positive (if I find a counterexample, it's definitely correct), and a reasonably small risk of false negatives.