# Is this stronger conjecture about near-rep digit prime numbers true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4568338/82961) post, I established an even stronger conjecture:

> If we have the number $1\ldots 1$ with $k\ge 3$ digits $1$ in decimal expansion, then we can replace a digit which is neither the first nor the last by one of $2,3,\ldots ,9$, to get a prime number.

More mathematically formulated

> Let $k\ge 3$ be an integer. Then, there exists an integer $j$ with $1\le j\le k-2$ and an integer $m$ with $1\le m\le 8$, such that $$\frac{10^k-1}{9}+m\cdot 10^j$$ is prime (which is a near-rep digit prime number as desired in the question).

This is a significant strengthening of what is asked in the question.

Heuristic: The desired prime is roughly $10^{k-1}$, a random number with approximately this magnitude is prime with probability about $\frac{1}{\ln(10)\cdot (k-1)}$ and since we have the choice of $8\cdot (k-2)$ numbers, for $k\ge 1000$, the expected number of primes is about $3.47$.

Computational result: The conjecture is true upto $k=1000$ (I proved the primality of the found examples until $k=500$ , for the rest of the range the very realiable BPSW-test was used).

Any idea, reference or extension of the search limit would be very welcome.

Comment: At a guess, there is probably enough variance in the heuristic that this one might not be true--unlike the linked weaker conjecture, which is likely true but also likely never to be proven true. Here though, it's easy to imagine that a variable centered at $3.5$ could reasonably slip below one for some $k$. *Finding* that first counterexample? Will be tough, law of large numbers and all. --- A last thought: you don't actually have a choice of $8$ values for $m$. Depending on $k$, you have $5$ or $6$ choices--the other $2$ or $3$ are guaranteed to be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Too long for one comment... for instance, for $k=5$, $m=2,5,8$ will give a number divisible by $3$ every time. So your heuristic should predict a smaller number than $3.5$, roughly $2/3$ of that.

Comment: @EricSnyder A good point. But the 1/ln-approach is anyway a rough heuristic. I did not consider , for example , that the numbers are never divisible by $2$ or $5$. Should the conjecture be false, the smallest counterexample would be very interesting.

Comment: Based on the extremely reliable BPSW-test (I do not think that any composite near rep-digit number passes this test) , the conjecture holds upto $k=2\ 030$

Comment: Yeah, if you've gotten out that far, I suspect that finding a first counterexample is a matter of either luck or time. It could be at $k=2033$ or it could be at $k=10^8$. I'm not sure what sort of direction you could go in terms of proof.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you allow $0$s? eg $10111$ is prime, $11011$ isn't etc.

Comment: @PeterPhipps I searched for a stronger still probably true conjecture.